# How do I record LOG in eosio smart contract?

Tags: smart-contract, eosjs, eosio.cdt, log, c#

I deployed and tested **eosio** smart contract. I want to record the logs of a smart contract using the **web API**. How can I do this? I searched but didn't get any satisfying answer.  I tried to get logs by accessing actions, using eos-sharp in **C#** as follow:

```
try
            {
                UInt64 sequence; UInt32 blocknumber; DateTime datetime; string actionaname; String Receiver; String Trxid;
                var r = getEos();
                var resultaction = await r.GetActions(constants.LOCALCODEACCOUNT, 0, 20);
                string jsondata = ""; string finalresult = "";

                string globalActionJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultaction);

                foreach (GlobalAction action in resultaction.actions)
                {
                    var test = action.action_trace.act;
                    sequence = Convert.ToUInt64(action.account_action_seq);
                    blocknumber = Convert.ToUInt32(action.block_num);
                    datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(action.block_time);
                    actionaname = test.name.Trim();
                    Receiver = action.action_trace.receipt.receiver.Trim();
                    Trxid = action.action_trace.trx_id.Trim();

                    var dataarguments = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test.data);
                    dataarguments = "[" + dataarguments + "]";
                    
                    jsondata += "{\"Sequence\":" + sequence + ",\"Block Number\":\"" + blocknumber + "\",\"Datetime\":\"" + datetime + "\",\"Action\":\"" + actionaname + "\",\"Receiver\":\"" + Receiver + "\",\"TransactionID\":\"" + Trxid + "\",\"Data\":" + dataarguments + "}"+",";

                }
                string removecomma = jsondata.Remove(jsondata.Length - 1);
                finalresult = "{\"Actions\":[" + removecomma + "]" + "}";
                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(finalresult);
                return finalresult;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
```

But here the problem is I can get only a certain number of actions. I need all the actions. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question but you are limiting the number of actions returned to 20 by

```
var resultaction = await r.GetActions(constants.LOCALCODEACCOUNT, 0, 20);
```

if you want more, just do

```
var resultaction = await r.GetActions(constants.LOCALCODEACCOUNT, 0, Int32.MaxValue);
```

or something similar.

You could also fetch the hole Block via the GetBlock()-method but casting/parsing actions will be different.

```
var transactionReceipts = r.GetBlock("someBlock").Result.transactions;
foreach (var transactionReceipt in transactionReceipts)
{
    // do stuff with transaction-objects
}
```

if you want to get a permanent stream of specific actions and the network you are using maintains dfuse-nodes, then I would recommend using [EosWsSharp](https://github.com/cmadh/EosWsSharp) instead of eos-sharp.

If you are requesting a very large amount of actions Nodeos maybe throws an exception depending on the configuration of the node.

Increase the values for

```
--http-max-bytes-in-flight-mb
```

and/or

```
--http-max-response-time-ms
```

to solve this. (Take a look at the [nodeos-config](https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/v2.1/nodeos/plugins/http_plugin/index) for detailed information)

Comment: Hi @cmadh, I don't want limited actions. I need all actions. Will `Int32.MaxValue` cause low performance?

Comment: It will be slower due to more computational work on the server- and client-side (far more iterations etc.) but I don't think it's slow unless your client-side algorithms are.

Comment: But what if in the future, the transactions are more than Int32.MaxValue?

Comment: if the number of actions exceeds Int32.MaxValue (2147483647), you definitely have to change the way you get the data (Probably even if it's far less but in the thousands or ten-thousands of actions). Fetching such an amount of actions at once doesn't make sense and will probably not work due to the size of the data/response. Better change your implementation to use r.GetBlock() or to leverage dfuse.

Comment: Okay, will check out. Thank you!

Comment: Hey @cmadh, my eos account has 54000 actions. I tried ```var resultaction = await r.GetActions(constants.LOCALCODEACCOUNT, 0, Int32.MaxValue);``` it's giving exception. If I try in some loop it's going very slow.  I am not getting your ```GetBlock``` solution clearly as I want account information to display. Please suggest.

Comment: sry for the late response @Varsh , I updated my answer with a solution. (At least I hope it solves your problem)

Comment: Anyways, I would still suggest to use dfuse and eoswssharp or a self-implemented HTTP-Client connected to dfuse. It offers much more functionality than the RPC-API + EosSharp does.